# QMediaPlaylist::addMedia() returns true for nonexistent files

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

The docs say that QMediaPlaylist::addMedia returns false if it fails:

> bool QMediaPlaylist::addMedia(const QMediaContent & content)
>   Append the media content to the playlist.
>   Returns true if the operation is successful, otherwise return false.

But this code will print true even though the file doesn't exist:

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
QMediaPlaylist *playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
qDebug() << playlist->addMedia(QUrl("this file doesn't exist.mp4"));
```

If the file doesn't exist how can the operation be considered successful?

Comment: Why do you think it should fail to add entry to playlist? It's a lot more complicated than just "file does exist". What if file exists but is not a valid media file? What if file is on network drive, and drive is not available right now, but ut will be available in few secs?

Comment: @KamilKlimek If it always returns true, what is the point of it being a bool at all? Why not a void? When could it return false if not here?

Comment: Probably what it returns depends on backend implementation - probably backend that you're using has no problem adding invalid url as it may become reachable sooner or later (or never!)

Comment: @KamilKlimek Well, my problem is I can't find out why my video is playing. I've posted a now question about that, however - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654457/qmediaplayererror-is-never-emitted-even-though-video-fails-to-play

Answer (score 1):

After stepping into the Qt sources, I saw that QMediaPlaylist::addMedia() calls `QMediaNetworkPlaylistProvider::addMedia()`, which always returns true:

```
bool QMediaPlaylist::addMedia(const QMediaContent &content)
{
    return d_func()->control->playlistProvider()->addMedia(content);
}

bool QMediaNetworkPlaylistProvider::addMedia(const QMediaContent &content)
{
    Q_D(QMediaNetworkPlaylistProvider);

    int pos = d->resources.count();

    emit mediaAboutToBeInserted(pos, pos);
    d->resources.append(content);
    emit mediaInserted(pos, pos);

    return true;
}
```

Although why it needs to return a bool that's always true is a mystery to me.